# How do you implement network separation between a physical host and a VM on the same device?

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine, hyper-v

I want to have a machine running a VM on Hyper-V or VirtualBox.

All traffic from the VM should go over a LAN connection (ideally with the physical LAN NIC restricted entirely to the VM and not visible to the host) and all network from the physical host should go over the wifi interface.

I've looked at various levels of disabling the host NIC network protocols but this disables the VM access to the NIC.

I think I can setup a routing table to force all known traffic requests to the services I want on the LAN and everything else can go to a default gateway on the Wifi route. So technically, I can make it work, but I'm keen to understand if there's a way to make the separation more visceral and preclude the host from any access to the NIC/LAN.

Comment: I am not familiar with Hyper-V or VirtualBox, but in vmware workstation (and thus I assume also in similar setups) you can use PCI[e] passthough to connect a device directly to the VM (and not to the host). Disabling virtual networking and directly attaching the VM to a dedicated NIC should work.

Answer (score 1):

I worked out how to do it so thought it worth posting for others.

- Remove all protocols on the physical host NIC properties (TCP4, TCP6 etc...) except the "VM Bridge Protocol"
- Set the VM NIC to "Bridged" in VirtualBox Network Properties
- VM now has full access to the physical NIC whilst the Physical Host has none.
- Physical Host will route all traffic via an active Wifi and cannot see the physical NIC in terms of Network Protocols.

Comment: I guess that is one way without extra hardware. +1

Answer (score 0):

There isn't really a way to do this.

All nics on the virtual machine are actually virtual nics with vmware drivers.

The host machine MUST have access to both network cards, otherwise the virtual drivers will fail to function. Typically the IP address assignment is a function of the host operating system as well.

Even IP rules won't work as if the network connection is bridged with the host, they will have the same IP. If it's natted, the source ip address will be hidden.

Comment: Thanks anyway but worked out how to do this through standard features of VirtualBox and Windows networking.  Solution posted.